# Download data as csv irrespective of pagination

Tags: angularjs

I have paginated the view to limit to 100. But when i want to export data as CSV im able to download only the data included in pagination. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution would be :

Follow below on Export button click event:
1.  Remove grid pagination.
2.  Populate CSV File.
3.  Set back grid pagination.

By doing this,  user experience will not change, as well as you will get all records into CSV without database hit.

Thanks
Hitesh Ajudiya

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout an Angular Directive called `ng-csv`: an AngularJS simple directive that turns arrays and objects into downloadable CSV files.
[ng-csv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv)